# Difference of Suprema

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum, riemann-integration

Is it true that for $f,g: [a,b] \rightarrow \Bbb R$, and if $f,g$ are bounded then

$$ |f(x) - g(x)| < \epsilon, \forall x \in [a,b] \implies |\sup(f(x)) - \sup(g(x))| < \epsilon$$

This was a remark made inside a proof done in class by my professor for a different theorem. I'm trying to follow along but I can't find a theorem in the book that shows this and trying to prove by definition was a mess for me. Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Note: you need $\leq$ in the second inequality for it to be true.

Answer (score 6):

Since $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ you have $f(x)<g(x)+\epsilon$ and so $\sup f\le \sup g+\epsilon$. A similar inequality with $f$ and $g$ interchanged holds and so
$$
\lvert\sup f-\sup g|\le\epsilon.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\left\|f\right\|:=\sup_{x\in[a,\:b]}|f(x)|\;\;\;\text{for }f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$$ is a norm on the $\mathbb R$-vector space of bounded functions from $[a,b]$ to $\mathbb R$ and hence the desired claim is just an application of the reverse triangle inequality.